# devspace: how to auto-scale deployments?

Tags: kubernetes, devspace

My deployment never auto-scale on DigitalOcean. I have on my `devspace.yaml`

```yaml
deployments:
- name: app
  namespace: "mynamespace"
  helm:
    componentChart: true
    values:
      replicas: 1
      autoScaling:
        horizontal:
          maxReplicas: 3
          averageCPU: 5m
          # averageRelativeCPU: 1
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: pablorsk/app
```

Always has 1 replica. I try with small values on `averageCPU` like 5m o `averageRelativeCPU` like 1, but never upgrade replicas on cluster.

```sh
$ kubectl get hpa
NAME     REFERENCE           TARGETS         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
app      Deployment/app      <unknown>/5m   1         3         1          13d
```

This is my node configuration on DigitalOcean:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the configuration of your `Horizontal Pod Autoscaling` object?

Comment: Hi @rock'nrolla, I just have previous yaml on `devspace.yaml`. I need to add a new section on yaml? Or an personalized kubernetes manifest? Or you need the generated manifest of app POD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HPA installation is required** for auto-scale deployments.

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
```

Then, you can see values for TARGETS

```
$ kubectl get hpa
NAME     REFERENCE           TARGETS         MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
app      Deployment/app      216/5m          1         3         1          1d
```

More information on [metrics-server repository](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server).